# infinity recyclerview for fixed count of items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll, linearlayoutmanager

I need something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

After last element of my `recyclerview` should be first element, and vice versa.
For example:

`View2, View3, View4, View1, View2, View3, View4, View1, View2...` and so on.

**EDIT**

ok, this is part of adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CarouselItemHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindImage(mItems.get(position % mItems.size()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

this is almost what I wanted, but infinity in only one of direction (left)

P.S Only five items in list

Comment: thows ArrayIndexOfBoundException() exception....

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: updated the issue